# Save Java GUI layout configuration (w/ a Desktop Pane) between uses

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, save

I'm developing a GUI and I would like to have it save its layout information between sessions. Specifically, if the user runs the gui, then moves the gui to a different part of the screen, I would like the gui to save that screen location before it closes so that the next time it opens it will open at the new screen location. I would like to do the same with for the width and height (to preserve any re sizing the user make to the gui).

Lastly, I use a Desktop Pane inside my GUI has multiple internal frames. I would really love to preserve the layout (screen position, height and width, iconified (minimized) or not) of each internal frame.

My question is, is there an easy, built in way to do this in java? Or do I need to do it manually. I searched around but couldn't find much on this topic.

I'm developing my GUI using Netbeans GUI editor. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `WindowListener` and in the `windowClosing()` call, save information about the GUI into a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) system, then `store` them into a file.

Upon constructing the GUI, read the properties file (if it exists) and set the properties of the components you want to maintain attributes for.

Make sure you use different names for each of the internal frames so that you don't overwrite the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You have any number of options.

### Storage

1. [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).  This is basically a `String` key/value pair which has `load` and `save` functionality.  You will need to be capable of parsing the values to and from `String` though
2. [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) API is a little more advanced then `Properties`, as it allows you to store primitives, but you lose the control over where these values are stored (more or less).  An [example](http://java.amitph.com/2012/10/java-preferences-api-introduction.html)
3. If you're really adventurous, you could use the [XML api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/), maybe even [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/).

### Capturing the events

The main window is actually easy.  Basically you just want to attach a `WindowListener` to the main window and monitor for the `windowClosing` event.  At which point you need to get the frame's bounds and persist through which ever means you wish.  Check out [How to write window listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

The desktop provides a few extra mechanism depending on your needs.

You can simply add [InternalFrameListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/InternalFrameListener.html) to each `JInternalFrame` and monitor the `internalFrameClosing` or `internalFrameClosed` events.

Or you could implement your own `DesktopManager` and override the `closeFrame` method.  I'd probably avoid this if you can, as the `DesktopManager` is different for each look and feel

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no libraries available to do that, you have to code all manually.
If you can move to other GUI frameworks like JDesktop it has a built-in function, but is tied with framework.